# Creating custom Menubar class in wxPython

Tags: python-3.x, menu, wxpython

I want to make a class for my menubar, like this:

```
class MainMenuBar(wx.MenuBar):
    """
    Creates the main menubar
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainMenuBar, self).__init__()

    Modmenu = wx.Menu()
    Modmenu.Append(101, 'Targeted Proteolysis')

    self.Append(Modmenu, 'Modules')
```

However, when I run the code I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

How come 'self' is not defined and how can I fix it?
I am using python 3.7 and wxPython 4.01

Comment: `self` is only valid inside a method which has `self` as an argument, not in the class's body. Looks like you just need to fix the indentation of your `__init__`.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thanks a lot